# Can one use a succa built by a non-Jew?

Tags: sukkah

Can one use a succa built by a non-Jew?  If not, how much involvement of a Jew is required to make the succa kosher?

Answer (score 3):

Shulchan Aruch writes [635/1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.635.1?lang=bi)

> סוכה אע"פ שלא נעשית לשם מצוה כשרה והוא שתהיה עשויה לצל כגון סוכת עכו"ם

As long as a Sukka was made - meaning if the schach was put up - to make shade, it is kosher, such as a one put up by a non Jew.